# Image blinking in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, javax.imageio

I have a problem with a game I am programming in Java. Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Graphics dbg;
    Image dbImage;
    static Image block;
    static Block block1 = new Block();
    static Image player1;
    static Player player = new Player(193, 143);

    public Game() {
        Image playerIcon = new ImageIcon("res/play.png").getImage();
        setSize(500, 400);
        setTitle("Game");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setIconImage(playerIcon);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(new InputHandler());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();
        Thread p = new Thread(player);
        p.start();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        try {
            dbImage = ImageIO.read(new File("res/background.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player1 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/play.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            block = ImageIO.read(new File("res/grass.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        draw(dbg);
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(player1, player.x, player.y, this);
        g.drawImage(block, block1.x, block1.y, this);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I only added this class because this is where i added the images. Comment if you want to see the other classes. The problem is the image player1 and block are blinking.

Comment: Try adding `setDoubleBuffered(true)` in the `Game` constructor.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi I thought everything in swing was double buffered by default :S

Comment: @Cruncher I think that line is required when you are drawing directly to the graphics context.

Comment: JFrame is double buffered by default.

Comment: Try moving the file I/O to the constructor or another method (cache the images and reference them from the drawing method).  Also, I think it's considered better practice to extend a JPanel and override `paintComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Never ever do file I/O on the EDT (Event Dispatcher Thread). The `paint(Graphics g)` method is invoked by AWT/Swing on the EDT, so you should not load images there (as Zebby Dee correctly points out). Initialize them in the constructor, or load via a SwingWorker or similar.
2. Don't invoke `repaint` from `paint`, as you indirectly do using your `draw` method. This will cause an endless repaint loop. If you need your game to repaint regularly, use a `Timer` or similar, to post `repaint` requests from a different thread, at regular intervals. For some reason you also pass the `Graphics`object of an image to the `draw` method, and never use it. I'm not sure what the intention is there.

The combination of these two issues causes the blinking effect.